# Is it possible to install python package AllenNLP on RPi4?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, allennlp

Is it already possible to install AllenNLP on Raspbian? I can install AllenNLP on Windows 10 Python 64 bit, but not yet on a RPi4.

I've already tried to install AllenNLP via Miniconda, pip and docker but none worked out for me.

Reference readme of their github: (https://github.com/allenai/allennlp#installation)

I'm kinda new in this world so if anyone would have a working allennlp package with these specifications:

- Raspbian 10 Buster
- aarch64
- Python 3.7

and specify the steps, it would be awesome!

Is there any wheel package already available?

I really want to use a Semantice Role Labeling model of AllenNLP (https://demo.allennlp.org/semantic-role-labeling/semantic-role-labeling) but when i try pip3 install allennlp==1.0.0 allennlp-models==1.0.0 i get this:

[image of pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR4nK.png)

Am I doing something wrong? I already have pytorch installed on version 1.6.0 (output of script.py)

Any help would be awesome!

Have a good day

Lennert

Comment: Awesome that you got AllenNLP running on Windows!  Would you be able to post some notes of what you did on https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/612?  A lot of our community has been interested in doing this, but none of us on the core team use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PyTorch isn't available for the RPi4. That's a hard dependency for AllenNLP. You could try building it from source. I have found that less difficult than it sounds.